# Is there a way to get large amounts of SOL on Devnet/Testnet

Tags: testing, devnet, testnet

For proper testing of our app, we need large amounts of SOL (upwards of 50,000 SOL) in Devnet and/or Testnet accounts.

The `solana airdrop` command is becoming more and more limited, both in terms of the max number of SOL that can be airdropped in one command (1 or 2), and the rate limits imposed.

I tried (and talked to) QuickNode, but they are quite restricted on that was well.

So the only chance would be to write a script to get 1 SOL every minute or so, and then wait a few years LOL.

Is there any way we can test with high SOL amounts in Testnet or Devnet? Localnet doesn't help us because the wallet connector doesn't work with localnet.

Comment: Still in need of an answer. Testing against a local validator doesn't help because @solana/wallet-adapter-* doesn't support local validators for some (?) reason... Need to do a system test of the whole system, including GUI, with real test data (including large SOL amounts). Happy to it with local validator - if only the wallet adapter would support it.

Comment: What problems do "these faucet SOL airdrop" solve by limiting in this manner? I mean what would happen if they airdrop 100 or more SOL at once so that people can focus on the REAL work peacefully. I mean airdropping `1 SOL` is not a help if testing a simple program is going to consume much more than that.  I dont get the rationale. WHY make thing difficult? Is it just to sound and look "important"?

Answer (score 2):

Use a local validator for testing if you need these large sums.

Also you're probably going to run serious activity which will be slow on either network and local validator will be faster.

Comment: Great tip. However, as I explicitly wrote in my question (at the very end), testing with a local validator won't work because the wallet adapter doesn't work with a local validator. So I can test the Program with the `tests` on a local validator. But we need to a system test of the whole system, including the GUI. The reasons why @solana/wallet-adapter-* doesn't support a local validator is beyond me, but it doesn't.

Comment: solflare supports custom RPC endpoint, not sure if you can supply to your local validator, worth a try.

Comment: My issue is not with any specific wallet, but with the wallet **adapter** that we're using in the GUI. We want to use that adapter (and not talk to the wallet directly) in order to support several wallets.

Comment: @AllBlooming Were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: @maddy, no. I just resigned...